# Установить background из bitmap

Tags: java, android

Встал вопрос. Можно ли как-то установить бэкграунд из bitmap?
Если нельзя, то можно ли как то засунуть изображение из bitmap в drawable?

Comment: читайте BitmapDrawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18870853/3212712):

```
BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

view.setBackground(ob);
```